# Get notification when the application becomes active / inactive

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

I have a dialog based MFC application and I want to get notified when the complete application becomes active or inactive. When the user switches to another application and comes back to my application I need to execute some code.

How can I do this?

I already tried OnActivate but that doesn't help me much. The main window will also becomes inactive when another window of the same application will open. That is not what I need.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what it is you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You receive [WM_ACTIVATEAPP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms632614(v=vs.85).aspx) when another window gets active that doesn't belong to your application.